# Android: Hide ActionBar on Specific Activities

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, themes, hide

Is there a way to hide the Android Action bar on specific activities for example the "Landing Page" of an android app? My application makes use of the tabbed Layout and therefore **requires** the action bar (unless there's a way to implement tabs without the action bar, in which case I can make the app fullscreen). Since an action bar ruins the look on a landing page, I want to be able to remove it on this specific layout only.

So is there a way to control/switch the 'fullscreen' and 'actionbar' themes dynamically? :)

[image]

Comment: `getActionBar().hide()`

Comment: That easy huh :D Add that as an answer and I'll mark it :) @tyczj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply just use `getActionBar().hide()` or if using the support library use `getSupportActionBar().hide()`

Answer (score 1):

You can set a theme for a specific activity inside your manifest using the android:theme attribute. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Programmatically you can also call `getActionBar().hide()` or `getSupportActionBar().hide()` when using the compat library, to hide the action bar